# sup of a function depending on a natural number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

While solving an exercise about uniform convergence, I needed to evaluate the sup of the following function in $\mathbb{R}$: $\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2x}$, which I think it should be 1/n (the value of the limit as x approaches 0), but I don't know how to properly justify it since I simply took the limit and claimed the result was actually the sup of my function. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x)= \frac{\sin nx }{n^2x} = \frac{1}{n}\frac{\sin nx }{nx}$.

You know that for any $y \neq 0$, $\lvert \sin y \rvert \lt \lvert y \rvert$. Hence for $x \neq 0$, $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \lt \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sup\limits_{x \neq 0} \lvert f_n(x) \rvert \le \frac{1}{n}$. But as

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f_x(x) = \frac{1}{n}$$ you can finally conclude that $$\sup\limits_{x \neq 0} \lvert f_x(x) \rvert = \frac{1}{n}$$